# Google Drive API remove permission from invitation email address

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have added permission to a folder in Google Drive through API method. I see the email (foobar@example.com) invitation in the Drive UI as well.

My problem is that when I try to remove the permission using:

```
$permissionId = $service->permissions->getIdForEmail($email)
$service->permissions->delete($fileId, $permissionId);
```

I get an error:

```
"code": 404,
"message": "Permission not found: xxxxxxxxxx"
```

How can you remove a permission from the invite using Google Drive API?

Comment: Are you able to delete the permission using the UI? can you perform other operations to that permission (e.g. update)?

Comment: I can delete permission using the UI, but for some reason I can not remove or update the permission from the Drive API. It seems I get actual permissionId from the `$service->permissions->getIdForEmail($email)` but when passing that permissionId to `delete` or `update` function I get error Permission not found: 523523642643643643"

Comment: Does it happen only for this specific email and this particular file? or can you reproduce it on different files?

Comment: Tried with different email address foobar@foobar.com and another file, still having same issue. Assigning permission from the SDK API is working, but for some reason removing does not work.

Comment: Have you tried testing in a different environment like the oauth playground or the api explorer? https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/   https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/delete

Comment: Also from the API explorer I get the same error (for foobar@example.com, even though invitation is there for the current file and email address):
`404 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Permission not found: 10984617413651119086",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Permission not found: 10984617413651119086"
 }
}
`

Comment: Also tried Oauth playground, same issue.

Comment: When calling "permissions.list" on that file, is the permission id for the email you want to delete the same id you get when calling  "permissions.getIdForEmail" ?

Comment: Seems that is the issue, the ID from permissions.list is different than permissions.getIdForEmail, how is that possible, even though the email address is same?

Comment: I'm not sure why the IDs are different. But given the scenario I would rely on the ID that comes from 'permissions.list' rather than the one from 'getIdforEmail'

Comment: Well, that is a bummer. Thanks a lot Gerardo for helping me out pinpoint the issue. Will report this to Google